Generate Nested JSON payload using JSON function Oracle 19c
Hi I created a query to generate JSON but I am getting ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply. I am using Oracle 19c.
Below is the query I wrote but my grouping is somehow repeating.When I use JSON_ARRAYAGG or JSON_OBJECTAGG it gives the above error.I am missing something .Do I have to call the table again?
  WITH sub(dept,phone,device,grp) AS
       (SELECT 'STAFF' ,'1234567890','google' ,1 FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 'STAFF' ,'0004567890','apple' ,1 FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 'CEO' ,'0094567890','google' ,1 FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 'CEO' ,'0055567890','google' ,1 FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 'MGR' ,'0085456789','google' ,2 FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 'MGR' ,'0704545478','google' ,2 FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 'MGR' ,'0654565460','apple' ,2 FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 'EXEC' ,'0084467890','apple' ,2 FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 'TRAINEE' ,'1234770000','apple' ,3 FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 'TRAINEE' ,'0354430000','apple' ,3 FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 'TRAINEE' ,'0067556557','google' ,3 FROM dual)
     
     SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(KEY 'grp'||grp VALUE
                            (JSON_OBJECTAGG(KEY device VALUE
                                             (JSON_ARRAY
                                                (JSON_OBJECT( KEY 'dept'  VALUE dept,
                                                              KEY 'sound' VALUE 'defeault.caf',
                                                              KEY 'token' VALUE  JSON_ARRAY(phone)
                                                            )
                                                )  
                                             )RETURNING CLOB PRETTY
                                          )
                               )  RETURNING CLOB PRETTY
                        ) AS result                        
       FROM sub GROUP BY grp;**
    
     - Expected Output
    
       {
        "grp1": 
        {
            "google": 
            [{"dept": "STAFF",
              "sound": "default.caf",
              "phone": ["1234567890"]
             },
             {"dept": "CEO",
              "sound": "default.caf",
              "phone": ["0094567890","0055567890"]
             }
            ],
            "apple": 
            [{"dept": "STAFF",
              "sound": "default.caf",
              "phone": ["0004567890"]
             }
            ]
        },
        "grp2": 
        {
            "google": 
            [{"dept": "MGR",
              "sound": "default.caf",
              "phone": ["0085456789","0704545478"]
             }
            ],
            "apple": 
            [{"dept": "MGR",
              "sound": "default.caf",
              "phone": ["0654565460"]
             },
             {"dept": "EXEC",
              "sound": "default.caf",
              "phone": ["0084467890"]
             }
            ]
        },
        "grp3": 
        {
            "google": 
            [{"dept": "TRAINEE",
              "sound": "default.caf",
              "phone": ["0067556557"]
             }
            ],
            "apple": 
            [{"dept": "TRAINEE",
              "sound": "default.caf",
              "phone": ["0354430000","1234770000"]
             }
            ]
        }
    }


On this simple data set, don't get any error in 19c, 21c and 23 ai.

@p3consulting The OP's query doesn't error but it also does not give the correct result as it generates invalid JSON with objects that have duplicates keys (fiddle).

You need to aggregate four times (not twice).

First by GROUP BY grp, device, dept
Then GROUP BY grp, device
Then GROUP BY grp
Finally aggregate over the entire result set.

SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(
         KEY 'grp'||grp VALUE JSON_OBJECTAGG(
           KEY device VALUE device_json
           RETURNING CLOB PRETTY
         )
         RETURNING CLOB PRETTY
       ) AS result 
FROM   (
  SELECT grp,
         device,
         JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'dept'  VALUE dept,
             KEY 'sound' VALUE 'default.caf',
             KEY 'token' VALUE phones
             RETURNING CLOB
           )
           RETURNING CLOB PRETTY
         ) AS device_json
  FROM   (
    SELECT grp,
           device,
           dept,
           JSON_ARRAYAGG(phone) AS phones
    FROM   sub  
    GROUP BY grp, device, dept
  )
  GROUP BY grp, device
)
GROUP BY grp;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE sub(dept,phone,device,grp) AS
  SELECT 'STAFF' ,'1234567890','google' ,1 FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'STAFF' ,'0004567890','apple' ,1 FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'CEO' ,'0094567890','google' ,1 FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'CEO' ,'0055567890','google' ,1 FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'MGR' ,'0085456789','google' ,2 FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'MGR' ,'0704545478','google' ,2 FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'MGR' ,'0654565460','apple' ,2 FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'EXEC' ,'0084467890','apple' ,2 FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'TRAINEE' ,'1234770000','apple' ,3 FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'TRAINEE' ,'0354430000','apple' ,3 FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'TRAINEE' ,'0067556557','google' ,3 FROM dual

Outputs:



RESULT




{  "grp1" : {  "apple" : [  {"dept":"STAFF","sound":"default.caf","token":["0004567890"]}],  "google" : [  {"dept":"CEO","sound":"default.caf","token":["0094567890","0055567890"]},  {"dept":"STAFF","sound":"default.caf","token":["1234567890"]}]},  "grp2" : {  "apple" : [  {"dept":"EXEC","sound":"default.caf","token":["0084467890"]},  {"dept":"MGR","sound":"default.caf","token":["0654565460"]}],  "google" : [  {"dept":"MGR","sound":"default.caf","token":["0085456789","0704545478"]}]},  "grp3" : {  "apple" : [  {"dept":"TRAINEE","sound":"default.caf","token":["1234770000","0354430000"]}],  "google" : [  {"dept":"TRAINEE","sound":"default.caf","token":["0067556557"]}]}}



fiddle

thank you for the query and the logic ,but I need to combine the phones if they are same dept and device and grp  for eg: TRAINEE with apple should be 1 with both phones in the array

@RajivA Updated - for that, aggregate four times.

I see, thank you very much for the update.Now I got some idea how to approach the nested json
